# Remove Background Image From Expanded Bubble Animation

Tags: javascript, tween

**This is the LINK:** https://majorlove.xyz/flavors31g-new-v1/

This animation consists of bubbles with an image at the centre. You can move around different bubbles using touchpad or mouse. When you click on a bubble it expands fullscreen to show some more content.

- When you click on any bubble it expands to show more details.
- What is required to be done is to not expand the background image but just the background color.
  or
- Remove background image when the bubble is expanded

Here's the script:

`` var main = {
    init: function (o) {
        this.vars();
        this.initContainer();
        this.initClose();
        this.initHideClose();
        this.prepareSprites();
        this.events();
        this.draw();
        setInterval(() => {
            this.updateProgress(false)
        }, 10)
        return this;
    },
    initContainer: function () {
        this.iscroll = new IScroll('#js-wrapper', {
            scrollX: true, freeScroll: true, mouseWheel: true, probeType: 3
        });
        var x = -this.centerX + this.wWidth / 2 + this.xOffset,
            y = -this.centerY + this.wHeight / 2 + this.yOffset;
        this.iscroll.scrollTo(x, y, 10);
    },
    vars: function () {
        this.S = 1;
        this.loadCnt = 0;
        this.maxLoadCnt = 8;
        this.BLOB_DURATION = 500;
        this.ext = this.isCanPlayMP3() ? 'mp3' : 'wav';
        this.isIE = this.isIE();
        this.isIOS = !!(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g.test(navigator.userAgent));
        this.isIOS && document.body.classList.add('ios');
        !this.isTabletMobile && document.body.classList.add('desktop');
        this.progressStep = (150 / this.maxLoadCnt) * (1 / 16);

        this.getDOMElements();

        this.particleRadius = parseInt(getComputedStyle(this.particles[0]).width, 10) / 2;
        this.particlesLength = this.particles.length;

        this.radPoint = mojs.helpers.getRadialPoint;
        this.particleBuffer = null;
        this.isOpen = false;
        this.blobBase = 1.6;
        this.blob = this.blobBase;
        this.blobShift = this.blobBase;
        this.xOffset = this.particleRadius + 25;
        this.yOffset = 1.4 * this.particleRadius;

        var styles = getComputedStyle(this.particlesContainer);
        this.width = parseInt(styles.width, 10);
        this.height = parseInt(styles.height, 10);

        this.prepareDust();
        this.calcDimentions();
        this.loadAssets();

        var i = this.particlesLength;
        while (i--) {
            var particle = this.particles[i];
            particle.x = parseInt(particle.getAttribute('data-left'), 10);
            particle.y = parseInt(particle.getAttribute('data-top'), 10);
        }

    },
    getDOMElements: function () {
        this.particlesContainer = document.querySelector('#scroller');
        this.particles = document.querySelectorAll('.particle');
        this.closeBtn = document.querySelector('#js-close-btn');
        this.blobCircle = document.querySelector('#js-blob-circle');
        this.blobEllipses = this.blobCircle.querySelectorAll('#js-blob-circle-ellipse')
        this.dust1 = document.querySelector('#js-dust-1');
        this.dust2 = document.querySelector('#js-dust-2');
        this.dust3 = document.querySelector('#js-dust-3');
        this.dust4 = document.querySelector('#js-dust-4');
        this.content = document.querySelector('#js-content');
        this.curtain = document.querySelector('#js-curtain');
        this.progress = document.querySelector('#js-progress');
        this.progressGrad = document.querySelector('#js-progress-gradient');
    },
    draw: function () {
        var origin = `${this.bubleCenter.x}px ${this.bubleCenter.y}px`,
            h = mojs.h, inEasing = mojs.easing.cubic.in, i = this.particlesLength;

        h.setPrefixedStyle(this.particlesContainer, 'perspective-origin', origin);

        while (i--) {
            this.particleBuffer = this.particles[i];
            var x = Math.abs(this.bubleCenter.x - this.particleBuffer.x),
                y = Math.abs(this.bubleCenter.y - this.particleBuffer.y),
                radius = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
                a = this.blob - (2 * radius) / this.size,
                b = this.blobShift - (2 * radius) / this.size, scaleMax = 1;

            var delta = mojs.helpers.clamp(inEasing(a), 0.03, scaleMax),
                deltaShift = h.clamp((inEasing(b)), 0.03, scaleMax),
                isDeltaChanged = this.particleBuffer.prevDelta !== delta;

            if (isDeltaChanged || this.particleBuffer.prevDeltaShift !== deltaShift) {
                var translateZ = -150 * (inEasing(1 - deltaShift)),
                    transform = `scale(${delta}) translateZ(${translateZ}px)`;
                h.setPrefixedStyle(this.particleBuffer, 'transform', transform);
                this.particleBuffer.prevDelta = delta;
                this.particleBuffer.prevDeltaShift = deltaShift;
            }
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(this.draw.bind(this));
    },
    calcDimentions: function () {
        this.wWidth = window.innerWidth;
        this.wHeight = window.innerHeight;
        this.centerY = this.height / 2 - this.wHeight / 2;
        this.centerX = this.width / 2 - this.wWidth / 2;
        this.bubleCenter = {x: this.centerX, y: this.centerY}
        var x = Math.sqrt(this.wHeight * this.wHeight),
            y = Math.sqrt(this.wWidth * this.wWidth);
        this.size = 1 * Math.min(x, y)
    },
    start: function () {
        this.curtain.classList.add('is-hide');
        this.startBlob();
    },
    startBlob: function () {
        var tween = new mojs.Tween;
        var t = new mojs.Timeline({
            duration: 1200 * this.S,
            onUpdate: (p) => {
                this.blob = this.blobBase + .3 * (1 - mojs.easing.elastic.out(p));
            }
        });

        var centerX = this.bubleCenter.x, centerY = this.bubleCenter.y;

        var t2 = new mojs.Timeline({
            duration: 1200 * this.S, delay: 0 * this.S,
            onUpdate: (p) => {
                this.blobShift = this.blobBase + .5 * (1 - mojs.easing.elastic.out(p));
            },
            onStart: () => {
                this.closeScaleSound.play()
            }
        });
        tween.add(t, t2);
        tween.start();
    },
    updateProgress: function (isReturn = true) {
        if (isReturn) {
            return
        }
        var shift = (this.maxLoadCnt - ++this.loadCnt) * this.progressStep;
        this.progress.style.width = `${shift}rem`;
        mojs.h.setPrefixedStyle(this.progressGrad, 'transform', `translateX(-${(this.loadCnt * this.progressStep / 1.3)}rem)`);
        (this.loadCnt === this.maxLoadCnt) && this.start();
    },
    loadAssets: function () {
        this.openSound = new Howl({
            urls: [`https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/6859/open-bubble-2.${this.ext}`],
            onload: this.updateProgress.bind(this)
        });
        this.openSound2 = new Howl({
            urls: [`https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/6859/open-bubble-3.${this.ext}`],
            rate: .15,
            onload: this.updateProgress.bind(this)
        });
        this.bounceSound = new Howl({urls: [`https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/6859/bounce.${this.ext}`]});
        this.closeSound = new Howl({
            urls: [`https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/6859/bubble-single-1.${this.ext}`],
            rate: .5,
            onload: this.updateProgress.bind(this)
        });
        this.closeSound2 = new Howl({
            urls: [`https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/6859/bubble-single-1.${this.ext}`],
            rate: .75,
            onload: this.updateProgress.bind(this)
        });
        this.closeSound3 = new Howl({
            urls: [`https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/6859/bubble-single-1.${this.ext}`],
            rate: .85,
            onload: this.updateProgress.bind(this)
        });
        this.closeScaleSound = new Howl({
            urls: [`https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/6859/open-bubble-3.${this.ext}`],
            rate: .25,
            onload: this.updateProgress.bind(this)
        });
        this.closeBtnSound = new Howl({
            urls: [`https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/6859/open-bubble-3.${this.ext}`],
            rate: 1,
            onload: this.updateProgress.bind(this)
        });
        this.loadImage('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/6859/mojs-logo.png');
    },
    loadImage: function (url) {
        var image = new Image;
        image.addEventListener('load', this.updateProgress.bind(this), false);
        image.addEventListener('error', this.updateProgress.bind(this), false);
        image.src = url;
    },
    isCanPlayMP3: function () {
        var userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
        return !(userAgent.indexOf("Opera") && (userAgent.indexOf('firefox') > -1));
    },
    isIE: function () {
        return !!(window.navigator.msPointerEnabled && !window.PointerEvent);
    },
    isTabletMobile: (function () {
        return /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
    })(),

    setBubblePosition: function () {
        this.bubleCenter.x = -this.iscroll.x + this.wWidth / 2 + this.xOffset;
        this.bubleCenter.y = -this.iscroll.y + this.wHeight / 2 + this.yOffset;
    },

    events: function () {
        window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
            this.calcDimentions();
            this.setBubblePosition()
        });
        (new Hammer(document.body)).on('tap', (e) => {
            var el = e.target.parentNode;
            if (this.isOpen) {
                return e.preventDefault()
            }
            if (el.classList.contains('particle')) {
                this.showOnEl(el);
            } else if (el.parentNode.classList.contains('particle')) {
                this.showOnEl(el.parentNode);
            }
        });
        (new Hammer(this.closeBtn)).on('tap', this.closeEl.bind(this));
        document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }, false);
        this.iscroll.on('scroll', this.setBubblePosition.bind(this));
    },
    initClose: function () {
        var dur = 400 * this.S;
        var closeOption = {
            parent: document.querySelector('#js-close-btn'),
            type: 'circle',
            radius: {0: 15},
            fill: 'transparent',
            stroke: 'white',
            strokeWidth: {5: 0},
            x: '50%', y: '50%',
            duration: dur,
            isRunLess: true
        }
        this.closeCircle = new mojs.Transit(closeOption);

        var closeCrossOption = {
            type: 'cross',
            delay: (.4 * dur),
            angle: 45,
            strokeWidth: 2,
            radius: {0: 8},
            isShowEnd: true,
            onStart: () => {
                this.closeSound.play();
            }
        };
        mojs.h.extend(closeCrossOption, closeOption);
        this.closeCross = new mojs.Transit(closeCrossOption);

        var closeBurstOption = {
            type: 'line',
            radius: {0: 30},
            strokeWidth: {4: 0},
            delay: (.4 * dur),
            childOptions: {radius: {5: 0}},
        }
        mojs.h.extend(closeBurstOption, closeOption);
        this.closeBurst = new mojs.Burst(closeBurstOption);

        var closeOption2 = {
            parent: document.querySelector('#js-close-btn'),
            type: 'circle',
            radius: {0: 10},
            fill: 'transparent',
            stroke: 'white',
            strokeWidth: {5: 0},
            x: '-20%', y: '-50%',
            isRunLess: true,
            delay: (.7 * dur),
            duration: 400 * this.S,
            onStart: () => {
                this.closeSound2.play();
            }
        }
        this.closeCircle2 = new mojs.Transit(closeOption2);

        var closeOption3 = {
            x: '80%', y: '-30%',
            radius: {0: 6},
            delay: (1.1 * dur),
            duration: 300 * this.S,
            onStart: () => {
                this.closeSound3.play();
            }
        }
        mojs.h.extend(closeOption3, closeOption2);
        this.closeCircle3 = new mojs.Transit(closeOption3);

        var closeOption4 = {
            x: '50%', y: '130%',
            radius: {0: 4},
            delay: (.9 * dur),
            duration: 200 * this.S,
            onStart: () => {
                this.closeSound3.play();
            }
        }
        mojs.h.extend(closeOption4, closeOption2);
        this.closeCircle4 = new mojs.Transit(closeOption4);

        this.showCloseBtnTween = new mojs.Tween;
        this.showCloseBtnTween.add(
            this.closeCircle.tween, this.closeCircle2.tween,
            this.closeCircle3.tween, this.closeCircle4.tween,
            this.closeCross.tween, this.closeBurst.tween
        );

    },
    showClose: function () {
        this.closeBtn.classList.add('is-show');
        this.showCloseBtnTween.start();
    },
    initHideClose: function () {
        this.hideBurst = new mojs.Burst({
            x: '50%', y: '50%',
            parent: this.closeBtn,
            radius: {0: 100},
            type: 'circle',
            fill: 'white',
            degree: 25,
            isSwirl: true,
            randomRadius: 1,
            isRunLess: true,
            childOptions: {radius: {'rand(12,5)': 0}},
            duration: 500 * this.S,
            onUpdate: (p) => {
                p = mojs.easing.cubic.in(p);
                mojs.h.setPrefixedStyle(this.closeCross.el, 'transform', `scale(${1 - p})`)
            },
            onStart: () => {
                this.closeBtnSound.play();
            },
            onComplete: () => {
                this.closeBtn.classList.remove('is-show');
                mojs.h.setPrefixedStyle(this.closeCross.el, 'transform', `none`);
            }
        });
        this.hideCircle = new mojs.Transit({
            x: '50%', y: '50%',
            parent: this.closeBtn,
            type: 'circle',
            radius: {0: 15},
            fill: 'transparent',
            stroke: 'white',
            strokeWidth: {8: 0},
            isRunLess: true,
            duration: 500 * this.S
        });
    },
    hideClose: function () {
        this.hideBurst.run();
        this.hideCircle.run();
    },
    closeEl: function () {
        this.iscroll.enabled = true;
        this.isOpen = false;
        this.hideClose()

        var innerEl = this.currentEl.querySelector('.particle__inner'),
            scaleDownTween = new mojs.Tween;

        var scaleDownTimeline = new mojs.Timeline({
            duration: 500 * this.S,
            onUpdate: (p) => {
                var np = 1 - p, npe = mojs.easing.cubic.inout(np),
                    scaleSize = .75 + 18 * npe, scale = `scale(${scaleSize})`;

                mojs.h.setPrefixedStyle(innerEl, 'transform', scale);
                mojs.h.setPrefixedStyle(this.content, 'transform', `scale(${npe})`);
            }
        });

        var scaleDownSoundTimeline = new mojs.Timeline({
            delay: 0 * this.S, onStart: () => {
                this.closeScaleSound.play()
            }
        });

        var scaleUpTimeline = new mojs.Timeline({
            duration: 1000 * this.S,
            onUpdate: (p) => {
                var scaleSize = .75 + .25 * mojs.easing.elastic.out(p),
                    scale = `scale(${scaleSize})`;
                mojs.h.setPrefixedStyle(innerEl, 'transform', scale);
            },
            onComplete: () => {
                if (this.isOpen) {
                    return mojs.h.setPrefixedStyle(this.content, 'transform', `translate3d(-5000px,-5000px,0)`);
                }
                mojs.h.setPrefixedStyle(this.content, 'transform', `translate3d(-5000px,-5000px,0)`);
            }
        });
        scaleDownTween.add(scaleDownTimeline);
        scaleDownTween.append(scaleUpTimeline);

        var blobTween = new mojs.Tween;
        var blobShiftDownTimeline = new mojs.Timeline({
            duration: 1200 * this.S, delay: 300 * this.S,
            onUpdate: (p) => {
                if (this.isOpen) {
                    return
                }
                this.blobShift = this.blobBase + (1 - mojs.easing.elastic.out(p));
            }
        });
        var blobDownTimeline = new mojs.Timeline({
            duration: 2100 * this.S, delay: 0 * this.S,
            onUpdate: (p) => {
                if (this.isOpen) {
                    return
                }
                this.blob = this.blobBase + .3 * (1 - mojs.easing.elastic.out(p));
            }
        });

        blobTween.add(blobShiftDownTimeline, blobDownTimeline, scaleDownSoundTimeline)

        this.jellyTween = new mojs.Tween;
        this.jellyTween.add(scaleDownTween, blobTween);
        this.jellyTween.start();
    },
    moveTextEl: function (el, p) {
        p = mojs.easing.cubic.out(p);
        var transform = `rotate(${90 * (1 - p)}deg) translateY(${200 * (1 - p)}%)`,
            transformOrigin = `left ${80 * (p)}%`;
        mojs.h.setPrefixedStyle(el, 'transform', transform);
        mojs.h.setPrefixedStyle(el, 'transform-origin', transformOrigin);
        el.style.opacity = mojs.easing.cubic.out(p);
    },

    prepareDust: function () {
        this.dust1Spriter = new mojs.Spriter({
            el: this.dust1,
            duration: 300 * this.S,
            delay: 275 * this.S,
            isRunLess: true
        });
        this.dust2Spriter = new mojs.Spriter({
            el: this.dust2,
            duration: 200 * this.S,
            delay: 575 * this.S,
            isRunLess: true
        });
        this.dust3Spriter = new mojs.Spriter({
            el: this.dust3,
            duration: 100 * this.S,
            delay: 725 * this.S,
            isRunLess: true
        });
    },

    runDust: function () {
        if (this.isTabletMobile || this.isIE) {
            return
        };
        this.dust1Spriter.run();
        this.dust2Spriter.run();
        this.dust3Spriter.run();
    },

    showInnerPlastic: function (el) {
        var tween = new mojs.Tween,
            image = el.querySelector('.image'),
            scene = el.querySelector('.shape'),
            shadow = el.querySelector('#js-shadow'),
            shadowWrap = el.querySelector('#js-shadow-wrap');

        this.runDust();

        var mp = new mojs.MotionPath({
            path: {x: -300, y: -300},
            curvature: {x: '75%', y: '50%'},
            offsetX: 300,
            offsetY: 300,
            el: image,
            duration: (this.isIE) ? 200 * this.S : 1000 * this.S,
            easing: 'cubic.out',
            onPosit: function (p, x, y, angle) {
                p = mojs.easing.expo.out(mojs.easing.cubic.in(p))
                var rotate = `rotateX(70deg) rotateZ(${-60 * (1 - p)}deg)`,
                    translate = `translateX(${x}px) translateY(${y}px)`,
                    scale = `scaleY(${2.5 - 1.5 * (p)})`
                mojs.h.setPrefixedStyle(shadow, 'transform', `${translate} ${rotate} ${scale}`)
                return `translate(${x}px, ${y}px)`;
            },
        });

        var opacityEasing = mojs.easing.path('M0,0 C0,0 32.1191406,0.314142863 40.1669859,0 C40.1669859,0.165327852 50.9999996,-112.569017 74.0660521,0 C80.8905119,-16.0420643 87.1001393,-19.621745 92.0689049,0 C92.0689049,1.54522552 95.3231688,-14.8615687 100,0'),
            bounceEasing = mojs.easing.path('M0,100 C28.3125,98.6523445 39.0445328,8.99375039 40.1669859,0 C40.1669859,-0.0485295402 50.9999996,152.873952 74.0660521,0 C80.8905119,21.9365596 87.1001393,26.7923438 92.0689049,0 C92.0689049,-1.92034044 95.3231688,20.3352347 100,0');

        var timeline1 = new mojs.Timeline({
            duration: (this.isIE) ? 200 * this.S : 800 * this.S,
            onStart: () => {
                mojs.h.setPrefixedStyle(this.content, 'transform', `translate3d(0,0,0)`);
            },
            onComplete: () => {
                this.showClose();
            },
            onUpdate: (p) => {
                var b = mojs.easing.bounce.out(p), bin = mojs.easing.bounce.in(p),
                    t = mojs.easing.cubic.out(p),
                    rotate = `rotateY(${90 * (1 - b)}deg) rotateX(${70 * (1 - t)}deg) rotateZ(${90 * (1 - t)}deg)`,
                    scale = `scaleX(${opacityEasing(p)})`,
                    transform = `translate(${(-300 * (mojs.easing.bounce.in(1 - p))) - 5}px, 2px) ${scale}`;
                mojs.h.setPrefixedStyle(scene, 'transform', `${rotate}`);
                mojs.h.setPrefixedStyle(scene, 'transform-origin', `${50 + 50 * t}% 100%`);
                mojs.h.setPrefixedStyle(shadowWrap, 'transform', transform);
                scene.style.opacity = mojs.easing.expo.out(p);
                shadow.style.opacity = .75 * bounceEasing(p);
            }
        });

        var soundTimeline = new mojs.Timeline({
            delay: 300 * this.S, onStart: () => {
                if (this.isIE) {
                    return
                }
                ;this.bounceSound.play();
            }
        });

        tween.add(timeline1, soundTimeline);
        tween.start();
    },
    prepareSprites: function () {
        this.blobSprite = new mojs.Spriter({
            el: this.blobCircle,
            duration: this.BLOB_DURATION * this.S,
            isRunLess: true
        })
    },

    showInnerCircle: function (x, y) {
        this.blobCircle.style.left = `${x}px`;
        this.blobCircle.style.top = `${y}px`;

        var tween = new mojs.Tween,
            size = Math.min(this.wWidth, this.wHeight),
            borderWidth = Math.min(10 * mojs.easing.cubic.in(size / 800), 20),
            blobCircleSize = 30 + 2 * borderWidth,
            strokeStep = (borderWidth / 2) / (this.blobEllipses.length),
            i = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < this.blobEllipses.length; i++) {
            var item = this.blobEllipses[i];
            item.setAttribute('stroke-width', borderWidth / 2 - i * strokeStep);
            item.setAttribute('rx', blobCircleSize / 2);
            item.setAttribute('ry', blobCircleSize / 2);
        }
        ;

        this.blobCircle.style.display = 'block';
        var blobCircleTm = new mojs.Timeline({
            duration: this.BLOB_DURATION * this.S,
            onStart: () => {
                this.blobSprite.run();
                this.openSound.play();
            },
            onUpdate: (p) => {
                var tr = `scale(${28 * p})`;
                mojs.h.setPrefixedStyle(this.blobCircle, 'transform', tr);
                this.blobCircle.style.opacity = 1 * (mojs.easing.cubic.in(1 - p));
            }
        });

        tween.add(blobCircleTm);
        tween.start();
    },

    showOnEl: function (el) {
        this.prevEl = this.currentEl;
        this.currentEl = el;
        title = el.getAttribute('title');
        description = el.getAttribute('description');
        img = el.getAttribute('image');
        document.getElementById('title').innerText = title;
        document.getElementById('description').innerText = description;
        document.getElementById('back-image').style.background = "url(" + img + ") no-repeat center center";
        this.prevEl && (this.prevEl.style['z-index'] = 0)
        // return immediately on edges
        if (el.delta < .2) {
            return
        }
        var x = el.x - this.wWidth / 2 - this.xOffset,
            y = el.y - this.wHeight / 2 - this.yOffset,
            innerEl = el.querySelector('.particle__inner'),
            contentEl = el.querySelector('.particle__content'),
            tween = new mojs.Tween;

        this.isOpen = true;
        el.style['z-index'] = 20;
        this.iscroll.enabled = false;
        this.showInnerCircle(el.x + 75, el.y + 75);
        this.iscroll.scrollTo(-x, -y, 500 * this.S);

        var soundTimeline = new mojs.Timeline({
            delay: 0 * this.S, onStart: () => {
                this.openSound2.play();
            }
        });

        var scaleDownTween = new mojs.Timeline({
            duration: 300 * this.S, easing: 'expo.out',
            onUpdate: (p) => {
                mojs.h.setPrefixedStyle(innerEl, 'transform', `scale(${1 - .25 * p})`);
                innerEl.style.opacity = 1 - .25 * p;
            }
        });

        var blobTimeline = new mojs.Timeline({
            duration: 600 * this.S, delay: 100 * this.S,
            onUpdate: (p) => {
                this.blob = this.blobBase + .3 * (mojs.easing.cubic.out(p));
                this.blobShift = this.blobBase + 1 * (p);
            }
        });

        mojs.h.setPrefixedStyle(this.content, 'transform', `translate3d(-5000px,-5000px,0)`);

        var scaleUpTimeline = new mojs.Timeline({
            duration: 600 * this.S, delay: 350 * this.S,
            onUpdate: (p) => {
                var scaleSize = 19 * mojs.easing.cubic.in(p);
                scaleSize = Math.max(.75, scaleSize);
                var scale = `scale(${scaleSize})`;
                mojs.h.setPrefixedStyle(innerEl, 'transform', scale);
                innerEl.style.opacity = .75 + .25 * mojs.easing.cubic.out(p)
            },
            onStart: () => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.showInnerPlastic(this.content);
                }, 400)
            },
            onComplete: () => {
                this.blobCircle.style.display = 'none';
            }
        });

        tween.add(scaleDownTween, soundTimeline, blobTimeline, scaleUpTimeline);
        tween.start();
    }
}
main.init(); ``

Comment: There is a huge amount of code here but I can’t see the relevant CSS, though it may be buried in the code. Could you boil the problem down to focus on a bubble being clicked. [link] https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example should help.

Comment: Just an observation: I looked at the website as the obvious solution would be to put the background image on a related (probably parent) element that isn't itself scaled. While there does seem to be such I found odd markup. For example, mulitple instances of id="js-particle-0" - is it trying to store multiple combinations of layout? It seemed a bit weird and difficult to pin down what needs altering. Normally the rule is that ids should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

While I have not found the relevant code to alter the given source, I have experimented with the website and it does look as though the parent element to the one holding the background-image at the moment could have the background image instead.

The parent does not scale in the way its child does on click so the background image will not expand.

This code run onload would do the relevant changes, but of course whoever understands your code will be able to implement a more maintainable way of changing this.

```
  let particles = document.querySelectorAll('div[id^="js-particle-"]');
  particles.forEach(particle => {
    let child = particle.firstElementChild;
    if (child != null) {
      particle.style.backgroundImage = child.style.backgroundImage;
      child.style.backgroundImage = 'none';
      particle.style.backgroundSize = child.style.backgroundSize;
      particle.style.backgroundRepeat = child.style.backgroundRepeat;
      particle.style.backgroundPosition = child.style.backgroundPosition;     
    }
  });
```

I can't test this properly so it's here just as a pointer to what can be done.

Comment: Hi A Haworth. Thanks for the help. Here is the full code on the following link: http://majorlove.xyz/flavors31g-new-v1.zip

Comment: I tested this code. It seems to remove the images from the bubbles even before they are expanded.

Comment: Whoops! Yes I had forgotten about background color still being set, apologies. Maybe an intermediate solution, a pseudo element, would help. I’ll have a look later.